Route53 Resolver Outbound Endpoint Not Working
I created an Outbound Endpoint Resolver in Route53 and I attached a Rule for our organization domain organization.com forwarded to the target DNS onpremises port 53.
However I still can't ping the organization.com in my EC2 instance in AWS.
I can ping the private IP address of organization.com successfully from EC2 Instance AWS going to onpremise server, but not the dns name (organization.com).
I checked this link, the troubleshoot outbound endpoints section and follow everything.

TCP & UDP port 53 allowed in SG inbound & outbound
No NACL inplace (Default)
I can telnet port 53 of the DNS server onpremises successfully.
I can ping the private ip address of organization.com successfully.
DNS resolution & DNS hostnames enabled in VPC
Added custom TCP & UDP port rage 1024-65535
Site to site VPN is working properly
Onpremises firewall is also allowing port  53

I'm expecting to resolve/connect to onpremises DNS name from AWS or to ping organization.com from AWS to onpremises via DNS name. Let me know if what is missing and appreciate any help. Thank you

"I still can't ping the organization.com in my EC2 instance in AWS"

Ping uses ICMP, have you allowed ICMP in your SG and also onprem firewall?


yes I have allowed ICMP in SG and I can successfully ping via private IP address.

Make the Security Group allows outbound traffic to the on-premise DNS.
The long answer
An Outbound Endpoint Resolver in Route53 is a proxy that executes DNS queries for the Rules defined for a VPC. How it works:

A DNS query comes to the VPC DNS resolver (VPC CIDR + 2 address).
The VPC DNS resolver matches DNS names to the Rules.
If a Rule matches, it uses the associated Outbound Endpoint Resolver (its IPs are the source IPs that talk to the on-premise DNS resolver) to resolve the DNS query.

Therefore, a Security Group attached to the Outbound Endpoint Resolver should:

The inbound rules allow DNS traffic originating from VPC. Do53 needs both tcp:53 and udp:53, and DoH needs tcp:443.
The outbound rules should enable traffic to your on-premise DNS resolver with appropriate ports.

To test the DNS resolution, an instance (EC2, etc.) is required in the VPC. nslookup my-on-premise-host should resolve the on-premise DNS record. dig, ping, curl, etc. works well too.
As a result, there is no way to talk to an Outbound Endpoint Resolver except to try to resolve a DNS record.
AWS configuration documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver-overview-DSN-queries-to-vpc.html
